# Deploy maven project ear in websphere

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, websphere-8

I am using eclipse JUNO integrated with websphere 8.5.My problem is that,my project is in MAVEN module so each time i have to clean and install the MAVEN Project to generate the EAR.

After EAR generation, I have to remove the ibm related xml's inside the META-INF folder and WEB-INF folder and then I have to open the administrative console in websphere to  deploy the EAR.This alone is taking huge amount of time.

Could any one please suggest a script to deploy and run the MAVEN project in websphere.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>SAMPLE_APP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>SAMPLE APP</name>

    <modules>
        <module>SAMPLE_APP_Props</module>
        <!-- Changes to UI Framework -->
        <module>SAMPLE_APP_UIFile</module>
        <module>SAMPLE_APP_Web</module>
        <module>SAMPLE_APP_EAR</module>
        <module>SAMPLE_APP_Forms</module>
        <module>SAMPLE_APP_Filters</module>
        <module>SAMPLE_APP_Logging</module>
        <module>SAMPLE_APP_Security</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>   
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

The below 2Files i have to remove before i deploy the generated ear in websphere.

ibm-application-bnd.xmi
ibm-application-ext.xmi

Comment: Show you pom file which sounds you are doing things wrong if you couldn't deploy the generated EAR directly to Websphere...

Comment: You can take IBM-specific XML configuration files (application.xml and ibm-application-bnd.xml, I guess), and put it into src/main/application/META-INF), and then use Maven EAR plugin to pack these files into EAR (hint: Maven EAR plugin uses attribute called earSourceDirectory, it takes all files from there and packs it into an EAR). But show us pom.xml that you use for build.

Comment: Hi thank you for your precious comments.I added the pom entry and i briefly explained the question.

Comment: You can exclude resources in your EAR pom as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html). See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/crun_app_install.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-14-2-1-0-1&lang=en) for all the options for deployment.